# How to make program run in linear time?

Tags: performance, prolog

So I would like to make this code to execute in linear time and I'm not sure what's making it take long than that so all help would be appriciated.
Sorry for not explaining earlier what the program does, medellangd is pretty much calculating the average length of the words sent in within the string.

```
medellangd([],0) :- !.
medellangd([Head1|[]], 0) :-
             \+ check(Head1), !.
medellangd([Head1|[]], 1) :- !.

medellangd(Text, AvgLen) :- 
                medel(Text, X, Y),
                AvgLen is X/Y.

medel([], 0, 0) :- !.
medel([Head1,Head2|Tail], Letters, Words) :- 
                check(Head1),
                check(Head2), !,
                medel([Head2|Tail], Letters1, Words),
                Letters is Letters1 + 1.

medel([Head1|Tail], Letters, Words) :- 
                check(Head1),
                medel(Tail, Letters1, Words1), !,
                Letters is Letters1 + 1,
                Words is Words1 + 1.

medel([_|T], Avg, Words) :-
                medel(T, Avg, Words).



% We check that the input is a letter.
check(X) :-
                (X >= 65, X =< 90);
                (X >= 97, X =< 122).
```

Comment: What is the program trying to do? You should add this info to your question, plus how you plan to run it.

Comment: Could you also translate `medel` and `medellangd`? Using english predicates would make the program easier to understand for non-swedish speakers.

Comment: @Aurélien: I think it computes average word length

Comment: Yeah exactly @CapelliC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, seems like it was my method of checking it that was the problem, by using char-type on head instead of my check it solved my problem and I got i to run in linear time.